# how to refer to an object with which func1 of class A is called when inside func2 of class B which is called using an object created in func1?

Tags: java, class, object

I have a class A and within class A I have function `func1` and `func2`.
In the same file I have class B and in that class B I have function `func3`.
In the main class, an object `obj1` of `class A` is declared.
With this object, `func1` of `class A` is called.
Within `func1` of `class A`, an object `obj2` of `class B` is created.
With this object, `func3` of `class B` is called.
Now within `func3` of `class B`, i want call `func2` of `class A` with the object `obj1`. For this I want to refer to that object from within `func3` of `class B`. Is it possible? If yes, how?

I tried using `this.this.func2` which wouldn't work.
For now I am passing the object `obj1` as an argument and it works fine. But I want to do the same without passing it because I want to use an array of objects and every time the object should differ

```
class A {
    int attr1, attr2;

    public void func1() {
        int attr1 = 3;
        int attr2 = 6;
        B obj2 = new B();
        obj2.func3();
    }

    public void func2() {
        this.attr1 = 5;
        this.attr2 = 10;
    }
}

class B {
    int atr1, atr2;

    public void func3() {
        atr1 = 4;
        atr2 = 8;
        // here I want to access the object obj1 to call the function func2()
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A obj1 = new A();
        A.func1();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Goion Why did you make `func1` static? That changes the question a lot!

Comment: @Andreas. Nice Catch. I usually paste code in Eclipse to indent it. It might have added it since user is calling `func1()` by class and not by instance of class. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

Yes.

> If yes, how?

**Option 1: Pass as parameter**

Pass `obj1` as parameter to `func3`.

Or more precisely, since `func3` is called from a method of `obj1`, pass `this` as the parameter value:

```
class A {
    public void func1()
    {
        B obj2 = new B();
        obj2.func3(this);
    }
}
```

```
class B {
    public void func3(A a)
    {
        a.func2();
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Pass to constructor**

Pass the `A` reference to the `B` constructor, and have `B` remember it in a field.

```
class A {
    public void func1()
    {
        B obj2 = new B(this);
        obj2.func3();
    }
}
```

```
class B {
    A a;
    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void func3()
    {
        this.a.func2();
    }
}
```

**Option 3: Inner class**

Make class `B` an inner class of `A`. Essentially the same as option 2, but the compiler handles the reference to `A` for you.

```
class A {
    public void func1()
    {
        B obj2 = new B();
        obj2.func3();
    }

    class B {
        public void func3()
        {
            A.this.func2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried option 1. to pass the object reference "this". But it wouldn't work.

Comment: and I don't want it to be an inner class coz then I can have only one instance of class B in A. whereas in my situation I require n no of objects of class B to be used in that function. And everytime I call func3 with a diff object created within func2.

Comment: instead of passing "this", I have passed the object obj1 from the main class to func1 of class A and from that to func3 of class B, as parameters. It works fine. But I wanted to know if there is any other method. And thanks for your reply. I haven't thought of option 2 you have mentioned.

Comment: @Kirthika *"I can have only one instance of class B in A"* That's not true. Why do you believe you can only have one instance of an inner class per outer class? That makes no sense.